# Access cookie from Client Side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies

I have set a cookie on the controller:

```
 HttpCookie loggedIn = new HttpCookie("LoggedIn", "true");
 Request.Cookies.Add(loggedIn);
```

I am trying to access this on document ready?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ('@Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"]' != null) {
        var loggedIn = '@Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"].Value';
        console.log("Logged In " + loggedIn);
    }

});
```

This keeps coming through as null?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually accessing the cookie from the client-side JavaScript. Even though you're sending the cookie back to the browser, your code is ignoring that cookie and trying to access it via a Razor expansion. I guess that could work, but it seems like a roundabout way to do it.

You can access cookies from JavaScript though the `document.cookie` property, which is a `;` delimited list of cookies.

Since you're using jQuery, a simpler way is to use the [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

```
var loggedIn = $.cookie('LoggedIn');
```

**Update**: I just realized you're setting the cookie in the request. You should be setting it in the response:

```
Response.SetCookie(loggedIn);
```

Comment: I tried that but it still shows as null, because i'm loading in a partial view would this have any effect on it?